# Transalation problems checkout

Tags: translate

I have translated "You can create an account after checkout." text and "Place order" button and the translation is displayed correct when Magento is set to developer mode, but when switching to default mode it goes back to the previous translation.

**I have tried this:**

rm -rf pub/static/*; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*; rm -rf generated/*; rm -rf var/cache/*; rm -rf var/page_cache/*

bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nb_NO -f

bin/magento cahce:flush

But the translation still does not change on frontend. I am all out of ideas, anyone experienced this before? Since the translation shows in developer mode it must be some cache/static files that is not updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. The store is using Amasty One Step Checkout, disabling built in JS and HTML bundling solved the issue. Seems it is not flushed with Magento native files.

[image: Backend settings checkout]

Answer (score 0):

Try in incognito mode, some translations are stored in browser cache

Comment: Inkognito does not either, still the same issue.